# AnyLogic -> adding batch agents to the default population. How the index of agents in this population will change?

Tags: anylogic

Good day. I have the following case  in AnyLogic:

Event -> Enter ->  Wait -> Batch

The Event generates the agents. The agents are generated by groups with the same timestamp and batchNumber.Then, in a Wait block I find all the agents in my population modalities with the same batchNumber. And collect these agents to the batch. The size of the batch is the sum of the agents sizes. This batch is inserted into the default population.

The problem is that in this case I can't calculate the index of a new agents in the Event (MyIndex). Whithout batch block it works.
I understand that one of the solution may be put the batches into the custom population. However, I don't fully understand what will happen in this case.
Do the  agents from the batch stay in the default population?

Or I am wrong and there should be another solution.

[image: Event]
[image: Wait]
[image: Batch]

Comment: i don't understand what your problem is, but just a side not, on add action should be += not =+ ... or maybe it should just be = ... depending on what resource_quantity is

Comment: @Felipe As far as I underastand the Event generates the agents and puts them to the population. When the agent goes through the Sink it is deleted from the population. Therefore I should calculate the index of the agents in the population for transmit it to the Enter (MyIndex). However the Batch also adds the new agent to that population every time it creates the batch. And I have to take it in account. Now I have error"Exception during discrete event execution. Index 3 out of bounds for length 1". I tried  to calculate the number of batches and deduct it in MyIndex. It doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do considering that you are using batches and agents in the same population, create an independent variable in Main called "agentIndex" and this index will increase every time an agent is created

```
Modality modality=add_modalities(blabla);
modality.index=agentIndex;
agentIndex++;
```

And that's it you dont need to get complicated...